# How rude is the "cockblock"?

Tags: slang, style, etymology

The word, not the act. Also, obviously not the Harry Dresden "Skin Game" version working with a trigger cock - since the cock we are talking about most definitely isn't a rooster (or is the obvious etymology false?), I was wondering how the "Fairly Oddparents", a kid program, got away with a title "Crock Blocked" (a pun on the Denzel Crocker character). Did "cockblock" wander from "slang" to "colloq." in the dictionary?

Oh, and another thing, is the cock in question thought to be blocker, blockee or both?

Comment: You seem to be confused between 'cock' and 'crock'. Also 'cock' in connection with firearms is a verb. You cock a gun, then you can pull the trigger and fire it. There is no 'trigger cock'. 'Cock' (noun) is slang for 'penis', and thus 'rude', but it also means a male chicken, and a type of valve (air, water, steam, etc), and these are not 'rude'.

Comment: Actually, it was a noun in the days of flintlock guns; it was the part holding the flint, and you 'cocked' the gun by pulling the cock back into the position from where it could be released by pulling the trigger to spring forward and strike sparks.

Comment: And if you only pulled the cock half-way back the gun would fail to fire properly hence the phrase going of at half-cock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Cockblocked" is vulgar and rude.

"Crock blocked" refers to this, but doesn't mention it. That makes the joke acceptable for a kids show. If you don't know the rude meaning, you won't be able to guess it. You will assume it is just about "blocking Mr Crocker".  If you do know the rude meaning - then there is an extra "adult" joke.

It's quite common for kids shows to put jokes that younger kids won't "get". Example

> Lego movie "My name is Richard Grayson, but the kids at the orphanage call me "Dick". /  "Well, kids can be cruel".

(Unless you know the rude meaning of "dick" you won't get why this is cruel.)

Comment: I knew that meaning of 'dick' when I was aged seven in 1959, but they were different times.

Comment: Well, I have my doubts that the Internet Generation [tm] (well, how long did the "Squid Game" take to the schoolyards?) doesn't "get" something... ;-)

Comment: *If* they get it, then that means they already know the rude meaning.  You can't learn the rude word from this.